# How to create a pipe to highlight the text in the sentence with given list of words

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a list of words and a sentence. I want to highlight the text in the sentence present in the list.

**For example:**

sentence :  "song nam person"

words :  ["song", "nam", "p"]

I want to create a pipe in typescript to produce the output like .

**song** **name** **p**erson.

I have tried this solution:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "highlight" })
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {  

  transform(text: string, searchWords: string[]): string {

    if (searchWords.length && text) {
      searchWords.forEach((searchWord: string) => {
        text = text.replace(searchWord, (match) => `<span class="highlightText">${match}</span>`);
      });
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

Problem with above solution:

1. it loop through the list of words.
2. it finds word "song" in the sentence and replaces it with `<span>` .

```html
<span class='highlightText'>song</span> nam person
```

3. Then it finds word "nam" and replaces it with the `<span>`

```html
<span class='highlightText'>song</span> <span class='highlightText'>nam</span> person
```

4. Then it search for "p" and replace the "p" inside the "span" too with the new span. which is creating a problem while displaying.

```html
<s <span class='highlightText'>p</span>an class='highlightText'>song</span> <span class='highlightText'>nam</span> <span class='highlightText'>person</span>
```

It would be grateful if someone can provide a solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Use a `directive`  have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936885/how-to-highlight-a-word-in-a-paragraph-in-angular-2)

Comment: The official docs actually have an example directive doing exactly this: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#build-a-simple-attribute-directive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial idea is quite good. Taking an input text and modifying it such as the output wraps the text with a given class.

With Angular, when you want to manipulate the DOM, there are 2 important things to keep in mind:
 - **Use a directive (not a pipe)**
 - **Use the renderer, never manipulate the DOM yourself**

That said, here's how I'd have build the directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, SimpleChanges, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  @Input() searchedWords: string[];
  @Input() text: string;
  @Input() classToApply: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (!this.searchedWords || !this.searchedWords.length || !this.classToApply) {
      this.renderer.setProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', this.text);
      return;
    }

    this.renderer.setProperty(
      this.el.nativeElement,
      'innerHTML',
      this.getFormattedText()
    );
  }

  getFormattedText() {
    const re = new RegExp(`(${ this.searchedWords.join('|') })`, 'g');

    return this.text.replace(re, `<span class="${this.classToApply}">$1</span>`);
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML you can call:

```
<p
  appHighlight
  [searchedWords]="['song', 'name', 'p']"
  text="song name person"
  classToApply="selected"
></p>
```

Of course, you can also build a dynamic version:

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  text = new FormControl('song name person')
  searchedWordsControl = new FormControl('')

  searchedWords$: Observable<string[]> = this
    .searchedWordsControl
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      map((search: string) => search.trim().split(' '))
    )
}
```

HTML:

```
Text:
<input type="text" placeholder="Text" [formControl]="text">

Searched words:
<input type="text" placeholder="Searched words" [formControl]="searchedWordsControl">

<p
  appHighlight
  [searchedWords]="searchedWords$ | async"
  [text]="text.value"
  classToApply="selected"
></p>
```

Here's a Stackblitz example with both the static and dynamic version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdfyuq

Comment: Thanks a lot that was really helpful and informative too :)